# Can the ArcGIS coordinate change be wrong?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am using my own Lambert Conformal Projection with following parameters.

```
False_Easting: 722.5,
False_Northing: 755.0,
Central_Meridian: -102.5,
Standard_Parallel_1: 20.0,
Standard_Parallel_2: 60.0,
Latitude_Of_Origin: 44.0,
User_Defined_Unit: 5000.0 m
```

I imported latitude-longitude data (WGS_1984) and converted its projection to my own projection above.

When I picked up one point having a coordinate of (`lat=41.408,lon=-73.590`)
, its coordinate is shown in ArcGIS as (`xi=1167.6, yj=774.8`).

However, when I calculate (xi,yj) of the point using WRF FORTRAN subroutine, it is (`xi=1166.3, yj=774.6`).

The error is about 1.3 grid (~6500 m). I think the difference between ArcGIS and WRF is too big.

Could you give me an advice for this problem?

Comment: There's a great deal of difference between "coordination" and "coordinate".

Comment: Please **edit** the question to state what WRF is, and what datum it uses.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.pkrc.net/wrf-lambert.html), WRF uses a sphere. You'd need to use the same sphere model when setting up your definition. Same page says 6370 km, which I'm pretty sure isn't predefined.